# Does a List<T> guarantee that items will be returned in the order they were added?

Tags: .net, list, collections

Does a `List<T>` always guarantee that items will be returned in the order they were added when enumerated?

***Updated***: Thanks for all the answers folks, puts my mind at ease. I had a quick poke around the `List<T>` class with .NET Reflector (should've probably done that in the first place) and indeed the underlying store is an array of `T` (`T[]`).

Comment: Although we've now determined, through both experiment and reverse engineering, that List<T> in its current form does indeed preserve order, it would be nice if Microsoft would make it official and put this guarantee in the documentation. Anybody reading this have some clout there?

Comment: @I.J.Kennedy effin A! and that goes for a whole bunch more of the MS docs. +1 to you. (+100 if I could). There are thousands maybe millions of MS developers spending time reverse engineering, testing etc, all because of the lack of a few words from MS. Don't they realise this? The years go by and nothing changes.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The List is index based and new items will always be added to the end of the list. You can insert items at a certain index so the next items will move one position.

So **yes**, you can use it *safely* that way...

> The List(T) class is the generic
> equivalent of the ArrayList class. It
> implements the IList(T) generic
> interface using an array whose size is
> dynamically increased as required.
>
> Elements in this collection can be
> accessed using an integer index.
> Indexes in this collection are
> zero-based.
>
> The List(T) is not guaranteed to be
> sorted. You must sort the List(T)
> before performing operations (such as
> BinarySearch) that require the List(T)
> to be sorted.
>
> A List(T) can support multiple readers
> concurrently, as long as the
> collection is not modified.
> Enumerating through a collection is
> intrinsically not a thread-safe
> procedure. In the rare case where an
> enumeration contends with one or more
> write accesses, the only way to ensure
> thread safety is to lock the
> collection during the entire
> enumeration. To allow the collection
> to be accessed by multiple threads for
> reading and writing, you must
> implement your own synchronization.

You can read more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Comment: It seems that the doc for List<T> does not state that the order of retrieval is the same as the order of insertion. It does behave that way, for now, but it is not documented to do so.

Comment: that's indeed correct, it is always good to be conscious about that, and when it's absolutely critical, to not count on it!

Comment: @Cheeso It does guarantee order of retrieval. I've added an answer that includes this detail.

Comment: Hi. You know if the behaviour is the same with the inline initialization?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) guarantees **both insertion order and retrieval order** and this is documented on MSDN (emphasis below is mine).

### Insertion

[**`List<T>.Add` Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx)

> Adds an object to the **end of the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)**.

Item parameter is:

> The object to be added to the **end of the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)**.

[**`List<T>.AddRange` Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)

> Adds the elements of the specified collection to the **end of the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)**.

Collection parameter is:

> The collection whose elements should be added to the **end of the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)**.

### Retrieval

[**`List<T>.Enumerator` Structure**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s.aspx)

> Initially, the enumerator is positioned before the first element in the collection. At this position, `Current` is undefined. Therefore, you must call `MoveNext` to advance the enumerator to the **first element of the collection** before reading the value of `Current`.

`Current` returns the same object until `MoveNext` is called. `MoveNext` sets `Current` to the **next element**.

Comment: Alex, I think you may have jumped to a conclusion which is not warranted. "The first element in the collection" is not necessarily the same as "the first element that was added to the collection." Likewise with the  "last element". The doc says nothing about order of retrieval being related to order of insertion.

Comment: Just wondering, `does AddRange()` preserve the order of the elements passed to it or is it free to muck around with order it adds them to the internal array? (Obviously they will all be at the end of the current list)

Comment: Alex is correct.  Microsoft's Add methods specifically refer to the order of the list (in this case, end).  As do the Insert methods ('specified index').

Comment: As soon as you notice that Lists<> have array indexers and the Insert() method (which takes an index) it should be obvious that they must be ordered. Both of these features require that this is the case. These methods form a contract with the end user of the class that these values will be available at the location specified unless you later move them.

Comment: Seems the docs are updated? It is now added to the AddRange descriptions:l https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange#remarks > *The order of the elements in the collection is preserved in the List<T>.*

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  But it's not part of the specification.

Ref: [List Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Comment: In that case, depending on this particular implementation detail would be a bug, no?

Comment: I can't find a reference for this, can you cite one?

Answer (score 2):

Yes according to this [MSDN Forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/24618c6e-3efe-4687-8ee3-74f47c18b997/)

Comment: This is a link only answer... any chance you can please include the context of that link?

Answer (score -2):

All of the answers under this questions are wrong. List does not guarantee the retrieval order; therefore, the question about the insertion order is moot. In real life tests, the retrieval order may or may not be the same as insertion order. However, Microsoft has collections that guarantee retrieval orders, but it does not expose them to developers. Those collections are all of the *ItemCollections used in Winforms GUI controls.

I struggled with the issue or insertion/retrieval order of List and had a problem whereby even `Insert(list.Count, item)` resulted in the new items being at zero position at retrieval, needless to say `Add` or `Append`, and the only solution was to ditch databinding and to `Add` items directly into the control's `Items`. That fixed the issue. Microsoft apparently enjoys torturing and misleading us, in its perpetual quest for bad karma.

Comment: I think you need to provide a concrete example as proof before claiming that "All of the answers under this questions are wrong.".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).