# Sort a collection based on another collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of file names with part of the pathname being a specific word. I can order the collection like this :

```
var files = from f in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<string>()
            orderby f.Substring(0,3)
            select f;
```

But now, I want to sort not by alphabetical order on the pathname part but according to specific order given by another collection.

So let's say the pathname part can be "ATE", "DET" and "RTI". I have another string collection : {"DET", "ATE", "RTI"} that I want to use to sort the filenames so that after sorting, filenames appear with their partname in the order "DET" first, then "ATE", then "RTI". How do I achieve this -> need to use an own comparer ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Sort List Based on Another List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355928/c-sharp-sort-list-based-on-another-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three different variants, depending if you want to use `string[]`, `List<string>` or a `Dictionary<string, int>` (good only if you have MANY elements to search for)

```
string[] collection = new[] { "DET", "ATE", "RTI" };
var files = from f in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<string>()
            orderby Array.IndexOf(collection, f.Substring(0, 3))
            select f;

List<string> collection2 = new List<string> { "DET", "ATE", "RTI" };
var files2 = from f in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<string>()
            orderby collection2.IndexOf(f.Substring(0, 3))
            select f;

Dictionary<string, int> collection3 = new Dictionary<string, int> 
            { { "DET", 1 }, { "ATE", 2 }, { "RTI", 3 } };

Func<string, int> getIndex = p =>
{
    int res;
    if (collection3.TryGetValue(p, out res))
    {
        return res;
    }
    return -1;
};

var files3 = from f in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<string>()
                orderby getIndex(f.Substring(0, 3))
                select f;
```

I'll add that LINQ doesn't have a "generic" `IndexOf` method, but you can build one as written here [How to get index using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2471588/613130)

Answer (score 7):

This should work

```
var files = from f in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<string>()
        orderby anotherCollection.IndexOf(f.Substring(0,3))
        select f;
```

Comment: Only if `anotherColletion` is a `List<string>` :-) (or some other collection type that has an `IndexOf` instance method. Arrays for example don't have it)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is as simple as you state and there are just 3 possible prefixes you could do this.

```
var fileNames = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<string>();
var files = fileNames.OrderBy(f => 
{
    int value = int.MaxValue;
    switch (f.Substring(0, 3))
    {
        case "DET":
            value = 1;
            break;
        case "ATE":
            value = 2;
            break;
        case "RTI":
            value = 3;
            break;
    }
    return vakue;
});
```