# C# : How to sort a list of object based on a list of string

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, collections, lambda

I'm having two list like

```
 List<String> l_lstNames = new List<String> { "A1", "A3", "A2", "A4", "A0" };

List<Test> l_lstStudents = new List<Test> 
                            { new Test { Age = 20, Name = "A0" }, 
                              new Test { Age = 21, Name = "A1" }, 
                              new Test { Age = 22, Name = "A2" }, 
                              new Test { Age = 23, Name = "A3" }, 
                              new Test { Age = 24, Name = "A4" }, 
                            };
```

Where `Test` is class like

```
 public class Test
    {
        public String Name;
        public Int32 Age;
    }
```

I need to sort the items in the `l_lstStudents` based on  the `l_lstNames`. So the sorted list will be like,

```
List<Test> l_lstStudents = new List<Test> 
                        {  new Test { Age = 21, Name = "A1" }, 
                           new Test { Age = 23, Name = "A3" }, 
                           new Test { Age = 22, Name = "A2" }, 
                           new Test { Age = 24, Name = "A4" }, 
                           new Test { Age = 20, Name = "A0" }, 
                        };
```

Now i'm using `for` to do this.

Like

1. Create a new list of `Test` objects.
2. Iterate the loop for `l_lstNames` and fetch the `Test` object from `l_lstStudent` and add the same to the newly created list. Finally assign the new list to `l_lstStudent`

Please help me to do this in a simple way ( Linq or Lambda)

Comment: I know you said simple, but are you more concerned with performance or few lines of code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Sort List Based on Another List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355928/c-sharp-sort-list-based-on-another-list)

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
l_lstStudents = l_lstStudents.OrderBy(s => l_lstNames.IndexOf(s.Name)).ToList()
```

I think that expresses the intention quite clearly.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
var studentLookup = l_lstStudents.ToDictionary(s => s.Name, s => s);
return l_lstNames.Select(n => studentLookup[n]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
List<String> l_lstNames = new List<String> { "A1", "A3", "A2", "A4", "A0" };

List<Test> l_lstStudents = new List<Test> 
                            { new Test { Age = 20, Name = "A0" }, 
                              new Test { Age = 21, Name = "A1" }, 
                              new Test { Age = 22, Name = "A2" }, 
                              new Test { Age = 23, Name = "A3" }, 
                              new Test { Age = 24, Name = "A4" }, 
                            };

// We transform the list in a dictionary to make it faster to access.
// The first Select creates a new object with the index of the name and 
// the ToDictionary creates the Dictionary.
// Note that technically on a small list (like 5 elements) 
// it's probably faster to IndexOf directly the List... 
// This is the problem of premature optimization :-) :-)
// If you know the list will always be 5 elements then probably 
// IndexOf is more than enough.
var dict = l_lstNames.Select((p, i) => new { Index = i, Name = p })
                     .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Index);

// We sort it. This works because 3 < 5 => 3 - 5 < 0, 5 > 3 => 5 - 3 > 0, 5 == 5 => 5 - 5 == 0
l_lstStudents.Sort((p, q) => dict[p.Name] - dict[q.Name]);

// We could do something like and it would be clearer.
l_lstStudents.Sort((p, q) => dict[p.Name].CompareTo(dict[q.Name]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
l_lstStudents = l_lstStudents.OrderBy(x => l_lstNames.IndexOf(x.Name)).ToList();
```

in a small test program

```
public class Test
{
    public String Name;
    public Int32 Age;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<String> l_lstNames = new List<String> { "A1", "A3", "A2", "A4", "A0" };

        List<Test> l_lstStudents = new List<Test> 
                                    { new Test { Age = 20, Name = "A0" }, 
                                      new Test { Age = 21, Name = "A1" }, 
                                      new Test { Age = 22, Name = "A2" }, 
                                      new Test { Age = 23, Name = "A3" }, 
                                      new Test { Age = 24, Name = "A4" }, 
                                    };

        l_lstStudents = l_lstStudents.OrderBy(x => l_lstNames.IndexOf(x.Name)).ToList();
    }
}
```

results in

```
Age     21      int  
Name    "A1"    string 

Age     23      int  
Name    "A3"    string  

Age     22      int  
Name    "A2"    string 

Age     24      int  
Name    "A4"    string  

Age     20      int  
Name    "A0"    string
```

and thus is:

```
List<Test> l_lstStudents = new List<Test> 
                        {  new Test { Age = 21, Name = "A1" }, 
                           new Test { Age = 23, Name = "A3" }, 
                           new Test { Age = 22, Name = "A2" }, 
                           new Test { Age = 24, Name = "A4" }, 
                           new Test { Age = 20, Name = "A0" }, 
                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Putting it in a dictionary may save some look up time:

```
int i = 0;
Dictionary<string, int> ordinalValues = l_lstNames.ToDictionary(name => name, name => i++);
var sortedStudents = l_lstStudents.OrderBy( a => ordinalValues[a.Name]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out with following code:

```
 l_lstStudents = (from name in l_lstNames
                  join student in l_lstStudents
                  on name equals student.Name
                  select student).ToList<Test>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newList = l_lstNames.Join(l_lstStudents, 
    s => s, 
    test => test.Name, 
    (s, test) => new Test { Name = s, Age = test.Age }
    ).ToList();
```