# C# Sorting a List based on the sequence of values from another List (different classes)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm currently stuck at a problem where I have 2 Lists, and I want to sort the second List according to a value from the first List, here is an example:

```
public class data
{
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public int ID{get; set}
}
public class dataToSort
{
    public int ID{get; set;}
    public string retrievedData{get; set}
    public string timeStamp{get; set}
}
```

So lets say I have 2 List objects, one for data and one for dataToSort, their contents below:

```
data: "Alpha", "80"           dataToSort: "21", "XA", "YA"
      "Beta", "47"                        "47", "XB", "YB"
      "Charlie", "153"                    "80", "XC", "YC"
      "Delta", "21"                       "153","XD", "YD"
```

So what I want to do is to make the order of dataToSort equal to the order of the IDs in data, like this:

```
dataToSort: "80", "XC", "YC"
            "47", "XB", "YB"
            "153","XD", "YD"
            "21", "XA", "YA"
```

I have tried googling for a way to Sort these but all the LINQ syntax confuses me and I have problems due to the difference in classes of each object :( The only way I can think of is to have a for loop to get the index of one List's ID and do something like a bubble sort, but its too much of a hassle and also inefficient. Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# : How to sort a list of object based on a list of string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633426/c-sharp-how-to-sort-a-list-of-object-based-on-a-list-of-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can join the two lists on the IDs:

```
var query = from x in data
            join y in dataToSort on x.ID equals y.ID
            select y;

var result = query.ToList();
```

This keeps the order of the first list `data`.

---

You can also easily combine the two lists this way:

```
var query = from x in data
            join y in dataToSort on x.ID equals y.ID
            select new
            {
                x.Name,
                x.ID,
                y.retrievedData,
                y.timeStamp,
            };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I roughly see how LINQ works from your example now, and it also works great! +1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can do the trick (pseudocode):

```
dataToSort sortedData;

foreach data
{
    sortedData.AddRange(from unsortedData.Where(x => x.ID == data.ID));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join both lists and order by `IndexOf`

```
var ordered = (from ds in dataToSort
              join d in data
              on ds.ID equals d.ID
              orderby data.IndexOf(d)
              select ds).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<data> lstofdata = new List<data>();
List<dataToSort> lstdataToSort = new List<dataToSort>();

var q = from d in lstofdata 
        join s in lstdataToSort on d.ID equals s.ID 
        orderby d.Name 
        select s
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var list = dataList
           .Select(data => dataToSortList
               .First(x => x.ID == data.ID)
           )
           .ToList();
```