# How can I insert an item into a List<T> without bumping the item at that index to the back?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, insert

I'm trying to Insert an item at the start of a list using `foo.Insert(0, bar);` but it seems that the item that was at index 0 before is getting bumped to the back of the list instead of moving to index 1. I've tried creating a new List and adding the values in order, but it looks messy/hacky.

Is there any clean way of doing this? If so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: you are doing something wrong, insert just shifts all items that a behind inserting position, so that previuos 0 item should get index 1

Comment: If you care about order, perhaps you should use [`Stack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete And Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I cannot reproduce that. If I insert at index 0, all other elements get simply shifted up. Nothing is moved to the end of the list.

Comment: Yes, use other type of collection. For example stack

Comment: Please provide some code since insert is shifting all elements >= index one index higher.

Comment: List<T> does preserve ordering - so not sure what's going on here, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043039/does-listt-guarantee-insertion-order will help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already said in comments, insert into `List<T>` preserve ordering, so described behaviour shouldn't happen.

Simple example:

```
var lst = new List<int> {1,2,3,4};
lst.Insert(0,0);
lst.Dump();
```

[image]

Comment: The source code guarantees it: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,49c519bce0cdbd82 line 677