# Can an Order be guranteed if return type is IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am currently working on refactoring some code, and came across this method.

```
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetDataItems()
```

which does this

```
    var data = EditorService
        .GetAllItem()
       .OrderBy(x => x.name);

    var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        string guid = item.guid;
        string name = item.name;
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(guid, name));
    }

    return list;
```

I am bit confused on whether the order itself make sense?
IEnumerable as I understand don't ensure that objects in the list is not ordered?
But in this case the underlying model is a list, will order then be guranteed?
or will this be ignored once it is returned?

Comment: You dont, there is a stray ";" that breaks the code after GetAllItem()

Comment: You get an IEnumerable that enumerates a presorted item list. But why not `return EditorService.GetAllItem().OrderBy(x => x.name).Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(item.guid, item.name)).ToList() `? (lacks try:catch, add to your leisure).

Comment: What sort of "guarantee" are you seeking? Are you trying to reason about *the current code* or about *any future changes to the code that avoid breaking the signature*?

Comment: `ienumerable doesn't guarantee order` is **not** the same as `ienumerable guarantees disorder`. it's 100% up to the implementing class. if _that_ guarantees order, then yes, your data is ordered.

Comment: However as a client you just see an `IEnumerable` and thus should not **assume** if or if not that collection is ordered. Just look into the docs for the method, if it guarantees or not. The type itself makes no statement about that at all.

Comment: [Does List<T> guarantee insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043039/does-listt-guarantee-insertion-order#:~:text=The%20List%3C%3E%20class%20does%20guarantee%20ordering%20-%20things,to%20be%20accurate.%20Therefore%20the%20order%20is%20guaranteed.) but if you need to maintain order after the first batch of insertions then you need a [SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

The variable data you show on your code snippet is of type System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable returned by that OrderBy linq statement.
The items you inserted on your returned list are ordered because of that. New items you add on that list, as you told, are not guranteed their order.