# How to order and groupby while maintaining list order using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How can I sort the following list of people using Linq, so that they are grouped by ID and that the order in which they were added is guaranteed to be maintained.

```
List<person>people = new List<person>(); 
people.Add(new Person(1, "joe"));
people.Add(new Person(1, "john"));
people.Add(new Person(2, "bob"));
people.Add(new Person(3, "tracy"));
people.Add(new Person(2, "harry"));
people.Add(new Person(1, "ellen")); 
people.Add(new Person(3, "mary"));
```

Result that I want:

```
Person(1, "joe")
Person(1, "john")
Person(1, "ellen")
Person(2, "bob")
Person(2, "harry")
Person(3, "tracy")
Person(3, "mary")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var result = people.Select((person,index)=>new{person,index})
      .OrderBy(pair => pair.person.ID)
      .ThenBy(pair => pair.index)
      .Select(pair => pair.person)
      .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be enough:

```
var orderedPeople = people.OrderBy(p => p.Id).ToList();
```

[`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) performs *a stable* sort:

> This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two
>   elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved.

And `List<T>` is [guarantee that items will be returned in the order they were added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453006/does-a-listt-guarantee-that-items-will-be-returned-in-the-order-they-were-adde). So you will get the result you want:

```
Person(1, "joe")
Person(1, "john")
Person(1, "ellen")
Person(2, "bob")
Person(2, "harry")
Person(3, "tracy")
Person(3, "mary")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order this list using LINQ by following way.....

```
var orderedList = from p in people
                   orderby p.Id ascending
                   select p;
```