# List in vb.net LIFO or FIFO and why?

Tags: vb.net, list

I have this list (Just a typical .net list)  and im adding a bunch of UI Items into it, the list is then taken for a Sub which goes through it with .getenumarator and While loop.

Now the question is how are my items retrived from this list ???

is that First in First out OR Last in First out OR the answer is non of above and ive totaly lost it !! in which case perhaps I need different or more info on something else.

Help out if you can ....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enumerator for List will go through the elements in the order they were added. So "FIFO" in case elements are added using .Add or .AddRange. But elements can of course also be inserted anywhere in the List using Insert.

See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453006/does-a-listt-guarantee-that-items-will-be-returned-in-the-order-they-were-adde) for more 'proof'. (It's not official!)

Comment: Brilliant.... Just as I was expecting, can you provide me with a link to support this please? , if there is one anywhere ....

Comment: Is a link really necessary? He's correct, it takes seconds to try. The only exception to this is if you insert items in a way that allow you to specify the index in that list. As such, there shouldn't be any documentation that is going to say "lists are FIFO".

Comment: Hard to ignore its Insert() method.  Or its ability to access any element in O(1).  Talking about LIFO/FIFO just obfuscates its abilities.

Comment: @Hans. Agreed. I've expanded my answer.

Comment: The first line of the documentation for List.Add ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx ) says "Adds an object to the end of the List(Of T)." The documentation for List.GetEnumerator ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765.aspx ) recommends using a ForEach loop rather than using an enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this list:

> name    gender
>   jess    female
>   mike    male

this loop:

```
dim str = ""
for each i as listviewitem in listview1.items
str &= i.text & " "
str &= i.subitems(0).text & " "
next
```

str = "name gender
       jess female
       mike male"

Comment: But that doesnt answer my question .... you just gave me a for each loop, there is already a loop there I just wanted to know with what logic do items get retrived from a list