# c#5.0 List and the foreach

Tags: c#, list

am working in vs2013 and c#
if I have list myguids;
if I am adding objects to a list, will they keep the order in which they were added into the list always when i do the foreach. 
my doubt is if they could be in different order. (any thoughts)
(assuming they are never sorted).

Thanks

Comment: Why not just try it? It takes about as much time to try as it did to post this.

Comment: @JeffreyWieder Although I understand your sentiment, perhaps the question really is asking whether it *necessarily* sorts it, not just whether it sorts it or not.

Comment: I see your point , I did tried...Thanks, I was wonder if could change like in Linq or any other way where we access them.

Comment: @jeffreywieder (and other downvoters) - testing it is useless. It might well be that writing 50 entries to a list and enumerating them back shows they are in the same order. That doesn't demonstrate that its a guaranteed property of a list, just that for some tests they come back in the same order. This is a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 2):

Lists are kept in the order you add them.  If you do:

```
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(4);
```

It is guaranteed the order will be 1, 2, 3, 4 as you iterate throughout the list, using foreach or LINQ.

Comment: thanks all for the quick answer, any place where I can read about this statement ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463926/list-in-vb-net-lifo-or-fifo-and-why.  Also, my 10+ years of experience with lists also verifies this claim 

Answer (score 0):

Yes Lists always preserve order...