# Reading xml correctly, but order gets messed later

Tags: c#, xml

I parse xml data from a file to a list of objects of this class:

```
public class VerificationSample
{
    public double DesiredA { get; set; }
    public double DesiredB { get; set; }
    public double DesiredC { get; set; }

    // ..

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadToFollowing("VerificationSample");

        this.DesiredA = (double)FileStructure.GetAttributeSafe(reader, "DesiredA", typeof(double));
        this.DesiredB = (double)FileStructure.GetAttributeSafe(reader, "DesiredB", typeof(double));
        this.DesiredC = (double)FileStructure.GetAttributeSafe(reader, "DesiredC", typeof(double));
        this.ReferenceNumber = (int)FileStructure.GetAttributeSafe(reader, "ReferenceNumber", typeof(int));
        // ..
    }
}
```

I read this sample xml:

```
  <VerificationSamples Count="4">
    <VerificationSample DesiredA="0.000" DesiredB="50.000" DesiredC="0.000" ReferenceNumber="0"/>
    <VerificationSample DesiredA="75.000" DesiredB="-3.000" DesiredC="0.000" ReferenceNumber="0"/>
    <VerificationSample DesiredA="-30.000" DesiredB="0.000" DesiredC="0.000" ReferenceNumber="1"/>
    <VerificationSample DesiredA="-2.000" DesiredB="-60.000" DesiredC="0.200" ReferenceNumber="1"/>
  </VerificationSamples>
```

Using this routine:

```
public void LoadFromFile(string path)
{
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);

    // ..

    reader.ReadToFollowing("VerificationSamples");
    int count = (int)FileStructure.GetAttributeSafe(reader, "Count", typeof(int));
    this.VerificationSamples.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        VerificationSample newVerificationSample = new VerificationSample();
        newVerificationSample.ReadXml(reader);
        this.VerificationSamples.Add(newVerificationSample);
    }
}
```

All is good so far and works like a charm. However, later when I execute another function where I try to access my `VerificationSamples` list to use some values of my objects, the order of the objects gets messed.. so first line in the xml (was the first object) but later it's the 3rd.. 2nd is the 1st.. 4th is the 2nd and so on (no obvious pattern). Does anyone imagine why???

Comment: It's because it's just grabbing the objects from the list arbitrarily - you will need to use `.OrderBy(x => x.SomeValue)` to return them in a particular order

Comment: @Geoff It never grabbed the xml lines randomly. It always starts with first line-> add object, second line -> add object .. etc. I watched it for many many times. What would you suggest as a solution for your argument if it is the case?

Comment: You're right - it will grab the XML lines sequentially - but when you're iterating over/grabbing the list again from memory, the in-memory "list" (`VerificationSamples` ?) will need sorting on a value; otherwise the order will seem "random"

Comment: Q for you @FirstStep - Do you want the `VerificationSamples` to be output in any particular order? Or are you just asking why they are being output arbitrarily?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer this question. Is your backing store a List<T>? Some other dynamic sequence? How is your Add method implemented? Did you write it? Is it a built-in method of a .NET class? Where is the code that tries to enumerate the items? Please provide more code and details.

Comment: @Ge I want my `Samples` to stay in the same order I read it from the xml, because later I measure and test against it so every `VerificationSample` should carry the correct value for its `TestedSample` match. I think I just noticed why: If I close the app, it saves the list in a database and then query the list from the database on app launch, where the order gets messed. Maybe I should hard code an OrderID in the xml and keep ordering my list by it. What do you think?

Comment: @Mike I did not over write the `Add()`. If I use the List _anywhere_ , even just for display, the order is messed. Read above comment maybe that is the case/solution

Comment: @FirstStep  think you're on the right lines with that approach. I would create an `Order` column in the database and make it an auto incrementing key (or similar). Or, instead you could do this when creating your collection from Xml (have a property on only the object that is set when you read the item). Then you can `.OrderBy(x => x.Order)` when you iterate your collection

Comment: @Geo exactly what was done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening due to a problem when retreiving data from the data base. It was fixed for now by adding a property in the xml `OrderID` that will be used as a reference for the order:

```
  <VerificationSamples Count="4">
    <VerificationSample DesiredA="0.000" DesiredB="50.000" DesiredC="0.000" ReferenceNumber="0" OrderID="1"/>
    <VerificationSample DesiredA="75.000" DesiredB="-3.000" DesiredC="0.000" ReferenceNumber="0" OrderID="2"/>
    <VerificationSample DesiredA="-30.000" DesiredB="0.000" DesiredC="0.000" ReferenceNumber="1" OrderID="3"/>
    <VerificationSample DesiredA="-2.000" DesiredB="-60.000" DesiredC="0.200" ReferenceNumber="1" OrderID="4"/>
  </VerificationSamples>
```

Anytime I retrieve the list from the data base, I just sort it by the OrderID. `VerificationSamples.OrderBy(x => x.OrderID);`

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not big,use XElement.

```
using System.Xml.Linq  
XElement file=XElement.Load(@"your path");  
foreach(var VerificationSample in file.Elements("VerificationSample"))   
{  
   // do want you want XElement type VerificationSample in order at the file  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mehmet for the suggestion. But XmlReader is everywhere in the code and changing that now is a time consuming process

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453006/does-a-listt-guarantee-that-items-will-be-returned-in-the-order-they-were-adde), `List<T>` guarantees both the order of insertion and the order of retrieval.

If the items are not coming out in the order in which they were added, there is some external force that is disrupting the order (sorting, perhaps).

Comment: Mike I spent time debugging exactly this case. I was looking for a Sort/Orderby function somewhere and I could not find any. I think the database is retrieving the data in an arbitrary way (bug). Fixed the case for now by hard coding an OrderID in the xml and keep it as my OrderReference