# C# LINQ GroupBy with where condition

Tags: c#, linq, validation

Do You know what is the easiest and efficient way to get a list after some 'where' + have a list of elements which didn't meet those where condition?

To be specific:

This is my working linq. It gets fileNames, split it to name and extension Tuple list and:
- the name should be unique
- the extension is taken based on sorted list (so gif first, if there is no gif for this name take png, then jpg then jpeg, any others extensions are not supported)

```
/// <summary>
/// Supported image extensions.
/// The list is sorted cause we have priorities here.
/// </summary>
SortedList<short, string> supportedExtensions = new SortedList<short, string> { { 1, "gif" }, { 2, "png" }, { 0, "jpg" }, { 4, "jpeg" } };


var filesList = Directory.GetFiles(string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\images", "\\"))
                            .Select(s => Tuple.Create(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1, s.LastIndexOf(@".") - 1 - s.LastIndexOf(@"\")), s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(@".") + 1)))
                            .Where(x => supportedExtensions.Values.Contains(x.Item2)) // only supported extensions here!
                            .GroupBy(g => g.Item1) // we are assured that every group has proper and at least one value
                            .Select(group => group.OrderBy(o => supportedExtensions.IndexOfValue(o.Item2)).First()); // get only one extension in each name group by priorities as in sorted list
```

The clue is that I also want the filesList which does not meet the condition in order to write those files names in the warning message (and then they can be forgotten).

I tried to do this in this way:

```
var fileListGroupedBySupportedExtension = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetFiles(string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\images", "\\")))
                            .Select(s => Tuple.Create(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1, s.LastIndexOf(@".") - 1 - s.LastIndexOf(@"\")), s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(@".") + 1)))
                            .GroupBy(g => supportedExtensions.Values.Contains(g.Item2));

var fileListWithSupportedExtension = fileListGroupedBySupportedExtension
                                .Where(gr => gr.Key == true);
```

but I don't know how to get into this list and make another where or select so I am obviously doing something wrong :)

Is this way correct while handling such validation/linq stuff?

Comment: Usually you use a Left Outer Join.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b.  A left outer join you can use the same list in both join items with different filters to get items in one filter that isn't in the 2nd filter.

Comment: Yes! I tried to get both sets with one query, but I got lost with grouping.. Left outer join is similar solution to [.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) - now question is which is better?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note: Please use the `System.IO.Path` methods. They will make life so much easier. You can get the file name without the extension using `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and the extension via `Path.GetExtension`. This makes it much more easy to understand what you are doing.

Second, the problem is that you are discarding all files that do not have extensions. You can avoid this and simply assign an empty extension, if the extension does not fall into your expected range and assign this the lowest priority. This basically exchanges your `where` in the first attempt with another `select` that resets the extension to `null`, if the extension is not supported.

Third, at least when your list of extensions does not change dynamically, you can as well use a regular `List`. This has a smaller overhead than a `SortedList`.

Comment: Thanks! 1. System.IO.Path and GetExtension method - You are perfectly right, I already changed it in my code. 2. Files without extensions - surely something to take in mind - I didn't, now I will. 3. I used sortedList because of the priorities of the extensions. 4. All of it didn't answer my question about validation, but are valuable - thanks for that! I'll put corrected code later to be easier to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like this:

```
  //DONE: You're trying to use Sorted List as a Dictionary
  Dictionary<string, int> supportedExtensions = 
    new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
      {".gif", 1},
      {".png", 2},
      {".jpg", 0},
      {".jpeg", 4},
    };

  //DONE: Enumerate - do not retrieve all the files and then continue working
  //DONE: Do no reinvent the wheel - Path class 
  var filesList = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "images"))
    .Where(file => supportedExtensions.ContainsKey(Path.GetExtension(file)))
    .GroupBy(file => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
    .Select(group => group
       .OrderBy(o => supportedExtensions[o])
       .First());
  //.ToArray(); // <- if you want the final materialization
```

**Edit:** let's compute `Path.GetExtension` just once (not very useful optimization, however); and let's select out `wanted` property (if file has a supported extension). We can do this with a help of anonymous class:

```
  var filesList = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "images"))
    .Select(file => {
       string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);      
       int extIndex;
       bool wanted = supportedExtensions.TryGetValue(extension, out extIndex);       

       return new {
         name = file,
         title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
         extension = extension,
         extIndex = wanted ? extIndex : -1,
         wanted = wanted, }; })
    .Where(item => item.wanted) // you may want to comment out this condition
    .GroupBy(item => item.title)  
    .Select(group => group
       .OrderBy(item => item.extIndex)
       .First()
       .name);
```

Comment: Very useful code - thanks for real demo with EnumerateFiles, Dictionary and Path in use. Although I have 2 questions: 1. In OrderBy i have to put Path.GetExtension(o) once more (it was done on the same collection just before), is this optimized enough to do this? It looks like doing the same thing twice. 2.This query still gets WANTED values and does not stock UNWANTED files name (in order to put it warning message later) - it's better to do some more grouping or just use "Except" for that list? What do You think?

Comment: Oh and I will call Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) later on in another method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove items from an IEnumerable, and so generate the items which don't match your condition.

```
List<string> all = AllFiles();

IEnumerable<string> matching    = all.Where(f => Condition(f));
IEnumerable<string> notMatching = all.Except(matching);
```

Comment: My first thought was "I don't want to iterate through the collection second time as I surely can do this in one iteration". My second thought was: "this is the clearest and the more bug-free solution I can think about". Thanks for reply for a real question, even if it's so easy and straightforward.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
List<string> supportedExtensions = new List<string> {".jpg", ".gif", ".png", ".jpeg"};// Supported extensions in valid order

var filesList = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\images")).Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToList(); // Get all files from directory
var filesWithoutSupportedExtensions = filesList.Where(x => !supportedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(x))).ToList(); // Get files that do not have supported extension
var filesWithSupportedExtensions = filesList.Where(x => supportedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(x))).ToList(); // Get files with supported extension
var firstFilesWithUniqueName = filesWithSupportedExtensions.GroupBy(x => Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(x), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)))
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(f => supportedExtensions.IndexOf(Path.GetExtension(f))).First()).ToList(); // Get file with unique name that has first extension from list
var otherFiles = filesWithSupportedExtensions.Except(firstFilesWithUniqueName).ToList(); // Get all other files

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, firstFilesWithUniqueName));
Console.WriteLine("Files without supported extensions:");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, filesWithoutSupportedExtensions));

Console.WriteLine("Files with duplicated name and different extension:");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, otherFiles));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I don't like this early materialization via ToList() + extension priorities will not work properly, list does not assure the order of elements.

Comment: Materialization of IEnumerable has it's benefits. When you call variable multiple times GetEnumerator would be called multiple times e.g. `var filesList = Directory.GetFiles(..).Select(...)` if I would leave it like this each call to fileList would call Select(...) method.

Comment: List<T> does not guarantee order of elements? I thought elements can be accessed by their index... I know it does not guarantee sorting, but order? See [Does a List<T> always guarantee that items will be returned in the order they were added when enumerated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453006/does-a-listt-guarantee-that-items-will-be-returned-in-the-order-they-were-adde)

Comment: OK, you are right about List in this case :)  (I still don't see it save in more advance solutions, with removing, adding etc. because it can cause bugs, when order is important I'd like to have it clear and obvious). I think I know what You mean with Materialization - I'd like to have only one query here, two maybe - but when step by step validation is needed then this materialization may be better indeed. Thanks for those remarks!