# Is there a way to have a collection of <char, int> pairs which both can have duplicate values in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, pairing

I wanna find the count of each character in a row in a given string.
For example "aabaccbb" has two 'a', one 'b', one 'a', two 'c', and two 'b'.

I wanna have a collection of <char,int> pairs and the order is important for me.
For example above like this:
{ {'a', 2}, {'b', 1}, {'a', 1}, {'c', 2}, {'b', 2} }

- "Dictionary<char, int>" can't have duplicate keys (char).
- "List< <KeyValuePair<char, int> >" is good but the key and value are read-only and I need to modify       them.
- "List<char, List<int>>" isn't suitable too because the order is important for me.

So what can I do?

Comment: Why not create a class with key and value properties?

Comment: @ibrahim-hamaty  yes that works and the only thing that comes to my mind is that too, but the class doesn't have so many methods that collections like 'List' have!!

Comment: @Ali_Hmt10, you don't need to create your own list. You need just to create your own _mutable_ replacement of `KeyValuePair`. For example, `record struct MutableKeyValuePair(char key, int value);`. Then you can store such a pairs into the normal built-in `List<T>`

Comment: As mostly a C++ user I was surprised that Microsoft has never explicitly stated that List<T> preserves the order of insertion, but for now it does, so List<MyCharIntPair> should work fine -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453006/does-a-listt-guarantee-that-items-will-be-returned-in-the-order-they-were-adde

Comment: Why do you need to modify the members of your `List`?

Comment: @NetMage for updating the count of character in a loop

Comment: No reason to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to make a class to hold the values for you and then make a list of that type

```
public class CharCount
{
    public char Char { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

then just create your list of that type

```
new List<CharCount>()
```

Comment: but I can't use some methods that exist in Collections. For example how can I look for  'a'  in this list with 'Contains()' method???

Comment: you can do any linq to filter so see if there is any 'a' you can do yourList.Any(v=>v.Char == 'a')
to find all that are 'a' you can do
yourList.Where(v=>v.Char == 'a')

Comment: yes you're right that works fine, but how about add, remove, ... !!

Comment: @Ali_Hmt10 It is a list, why can't you just call `List<T>.Add` or `List<T>.Remove` or `List<T>.RemoveAll`?

Comment: @NetMage to do that we have to create object and use 'new', I just need something like normal collections like **mylist.Add('c', 5)** not **mylist.Add(new myClass ('c',  5))**

Comment: `List<T>` is a normal collection, I'm not sure what you mean. What other collection behaves the way you want? If you want to avoid object creation overhead (are you doing this a lot?), use a `ValueTuple`: `mylist.Add(('c', 5))`

Comment: @NetMage how to use ValueTuple like that??, I say again that I might modify the elements

Comment: @Ali_Hmt10 Why would you modify the elements once you have the correct count?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class

```
public class MyChar
{
    public char Char { get; set; }
    public int Num { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this.

```
        string str = "aabaccbb";
        Dictionary<int, MyChar> pairs = new Dictionary<int, MyChar>();

        var chars = str.ToArray();
        int charNo = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            int j = 1;
            while (i + j < chars.Length && chars[i + j] == chars[i])
                j++;

            pairs[charNo] = new MyChar { Char = chars[i], Num = j }; 
            i += j - 1;
            charNo++;
        }
```

Comment: Don't you think the 'int' in **<int, MyChar>** is not necessary ??

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension method that counts runs of items from an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can just convert to an array to get an ordered collection of items and counts:

```
var s = "aabaccbb";
var ans = s.CountRuns()
           .ToArray();
```

Here is the extension:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int>> CountRuns<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEqualityComparer<T> cmp = null) {
        cmp = cmp ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

        using (var itemsEnum = items.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (itemsEnum.MoveNext()) {
                var key = itemsEnum.Current;
                var count = 1;
                while (itemsEnum.MoveNext()) {
                    if (cmp.Equals(key, itemsEnum.Current))
                        ++count;
                    else {
                        yield return new KeyValuePair<T, int>(key, count);
                        key = itemsEnum.Current;
                        count = 1;
                    }
                }
                yield return new KeyValuePair<T, int>(key, count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```